# triggering a click event on a selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, selector

I'm trying to get a click event to go off manual for a plug-in that uses a selector.

plug-in set up.

```
 $( function ()
            {
                $.contextMenu( {
                    selector: '.context-menu-one',
                    callback: function ( key, options )
                    {
                        var m = "clicked: " + key;
                        window.console && console.log( m ) || alert( m );
                    },
                    items: {
                        "edit": { name: "Edit", icon: "edit" },
                        "cut": { name: "Cut", icon: "cut" },
                        "copy": { name: "Copy", icon: "copy" },
                        "paste": { name: "Paste", icon: "paste" },
                        "delete": { name: "Delete", icon: "delete" },
                        "sep1": "---------",
                        "quit": { name: "Quit", icon: "quit" }
                    }
                } );

                $( '.context-menu-one' ).on( 'click', function ( e )
                {
                    alert( 'clicked', this );
                } )
            } );
```

I tried two ways to fire but I'm not able to make it work.
$( '.context-menu-one' ).trigger( 'click' );
or
$( '.context-menu-one' ).click();

Is there a special way to fire on a selector. I figured this was explained somewhere but my searching has reached its end.

--------- update adding more of the surrounding code -----------

```
 //local functions
    $( function ()
    {//override right click.

        $( this ).bind( "contextmenu", function ( e )
        {
            alert( 1 );// users right clicked
            var overRide = true;

            //set up the right click menu
            $( function ()
            {
                $.contextMenu( {
                    selector: '.context-menu-one',
                    callback: function ( key, options )
                    {
                        var m = "clicked: " + key;
                        window.console && console.log( m ) || alert( m );
                    },
                    items: {
                        "edit": { name: "Edit", icon: "edit" },
                        "cut": { name: "Cut", icon: "cut" },
                        "copy": { name: "Copy", icon: "copy" },
                        "paste": { name: "Paste", icon: "paste" },
                        "delete": { name: "Delete", icon: "delete" },
                        "sep1": "---------",
                        "quit": { name: "Quit", icon: "quit" }
                    }
                } );

                $( '.context-menu-one' ).on( 'click', function ( e )
                {
                    alert( 'clicked', this );
                } )
            } );

            //bring up the menu
            $( '.context-menu-one' ).trigger( {
                type: 'mousedown',
                which: 1
            } );

            if (overRide)  e.preventDefault();
        } );
    } );
```

My intent here is simply to trigger a right click so that the menu comes up manually not based on an event.

Comment: How does your html 'context-menu-one' look? Where do you want to trigger the click?

Comment: just added an edit above, I want it to trigger just after its built. I already caught my right click, I then build my menu, just cant get it to come up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on documentation taken from documentation [demo](http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo/trigger-custom.html). Following example waits for document to load and after a delay of 1 second programatically opens context menu:

```
<body>
    <div class="dummyDiv box menu-1"/>
</body>
<script>
$(function(){
    $.contextMenu({
        selector: '.dummyDiv', 
        trigger: 'none',
        items: {
            "edit": {name: "Edit", icon: "edit"},
            "cut": {name: "Cut", icon: "cut"},
            "copy": {name: "Copy", icon: "copy"},
            "paste": {name: "Paste", icon: "paste"},
            "delete": {name: "Delete", icon: "delete"},
            "sep1": "---------",
            "quit": {name: "Quit", icon: "quit"}
        }
    });

    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.dummyDiv').contextMenu();
    }, 1000);       
 });
</script>
```

Comment: I think I failed to explain myself well. I want to programmatically trigger the menu to come up. I "think" to do that I need to trigger the call back on '.context-menu-one' selector. I tried to use this event idea and then call that event but it still will not bring up a menu or alert "CLICKED!".

Comment: I see exactly what you did here and it does help simplify things. I certainly dont want the trigger to be based on an event but rather in code. So I simply added $( '#activate-menu' ).click(); but still no luck. I tried to put in alert in the #activate-menu event but even that didnt fire. There has to be some I'm over looking here.

Comment: but it does work if I add that button and click it. the click()  seems to work now that the html is there. Is there no way to do thi with out a button to click on and adding html?

Comment: right I "should" be able to but I cant make it work. though thx for this it helps.

Comment: I think my under laying issue is that I dont use the class "context-menu-one" so its does not know where to build the menu. I may have to add a dummy div first.

Comment: that was it... Just my misunderstanding. Now that I have a div it has somewhere to draw to.

Comment: I think we can safely delete those comments now.

Answer (score 0):

Try [triggering](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/#example-5) it by:

```
$('.context-menu-one').trigger({
    type: 'mousedown',
    which: 1
});
```

Comment: Didn't work, in this case I think the click is a right click, would mouse down work for that?

Comment: I've edited my answer to simulate a right click with [event.which](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) set to 1, should work with mouse down.

Comment: Still no dice, I added more code above thinking maybe there is more to my issue